# Validation control range validator usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am trying to create a registration page for my website. Here I have used range  validator for the validation purpose here is my code

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:right" >Zipcode:</td>
    <td style="text-align:center" >
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" MaxLength="6" runat="server" Width="350px">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="please enter your area zipcode" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox6">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox6" MinimumValue="6" runat="server"  ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="zipcode should be 6 characters">
        </asp:RangeValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But I am getting some error like

> The MaximumValue  cannot be less than the MinimumValue 6 of RangeValidator1

Somebody please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a `MaximumValue` attribute on your RangeVaildator, and you need to set the `Type` attribute as well.

Bear in mind though that the way you have it set up currently, this validator will not ensure that the user is entering in a minimum of six digits though, since your `MinimumValue` is only 6. You would probably be better off using a RegularExpressionValidator.

Comment: yes i set maximumvalue property this is my code  <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox6" MinimumValue="6" runat="server" MaximumValue="6"  ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="zipcode should be 6 characters"></asp:RangeValidator> but i am getting the same error

Comment: Not according to the code you have posted in your question. If you have set `MaximumValue` then, per the error that you posted, *it needs to be greater than 6*.

Comment: but i want my zipcode to be exactly 6 characters.how to do it?any suggetions?

Comment: As I already mentioned in my answer, RangeValidator will not do that. It only checks that an entered value is within the range specified by those two parameters. You should use a RegularExpressionValidator.